# Wordpress Custom Gallery Function

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I need to change some code from the WP-Bootstrap Wordpress Files.

In their code they remove the standard gallery code and replace it with their own which works fine accept it doesn't properly account for Rows.

```
function gallery_shortcode_tbs($attr) {
global $post, $wp_locale;

$output = "";

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    $output = '<div class="row-fluid"><ul class="thumbnails">';
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $output .= '<li class="span3">';
        $att_title = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , 'thumbnail', true );
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul></div>';
}

return $output;
}
```

could anyone advise on how to edit the above code to insert html code to close the row and start another after the 3rd item.. or any number i choose?

thank you in advance.

R

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the default WP gallery shortcode source, where a break is inserted after the specified number of columns, on lines [837-838](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L837):

```
if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
    $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, although i have a good understanding of what the code means I'm unsure how to implement it to the code in my question. with the code you supplied i will need to put $i = 0 somewhere i assume?. could you expand on your answer?

Comment: diggy could you expand?